# Matrix of Monte Carlo samples in R

Tags: r, montecarlo

I'm trying to take random samples from UK population projections and store them in a matrix.

At the moment, I'm using the following code

```
# Read in Data
Year = data.frame(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014)
Mean_ONS_Population_Growth = data.frame(0.0076, 0.0158, 0.0240, 0.0323, 0.0404)
SD_ONS_Population_Growth = data.frame(0.0003, 0.0015, 0.0029, 0.0045, 0.006193468)

MC_RUNS = 1000 # Specify number of runs

Projected_Population_Growth = array(0,dim=c(49,MC_RUNS,5)) # Specify number of runs

Projected_Population_Growth = rnorm(MC_RUNS,mean=Mean_ONS_Population_Growth,sd=SD_ONS_Population_Growth)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error in rnorm(MC_RUNS, mean = Mean_ONS_Population_Growth, sd = SD_ONS_Population_Growth) :
 invalid arguments
```

Ideally, I would like a matrix with 1000 columns and 5 rows - each row representing a year and each column representing a random chosen Monte Carlo sample.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapply(rnorm,mean=Mean_ONS_Population_Growth,sd=SD_ONS_Population_Growth,MoreArgs=list(n=MC_RUNS))
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: There is no link - are you intending to comment on another answer?

Comment: The main point is that an answer should have some explanation with it not just one line of code

Answer (score 1):

the function `rnorm` in R can only handle univariate distributions. I'm not aware of any base package including functions for multivariate distributions but you can check out [cran](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html). I personally prefer the package [mvtnorm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html). Included in that package is the function `rmvnorm` which is basically the multivariate version of `rnorm`. Though if you want to have independent univariate distributions, you could do an `sapply` for example like this:

```
sapply(1:length(Mean_ONS_Population_Growth), 
    function(iMC) {
        rnorm(MC_RUNS, 
            mean=as.numeric(Mean_ONS_Population_Growth[iMC]),
            sd=as.numeric(SD_ONS_Population_Growth[iMC]))
     }
)
```

One issue you have with your code is, that `rnorm` takes only numerics as arguments.

```
class(Mean_ONS_Population_Growth[1])
[1] "data.frame"
```

Hth,
D